# Emotion analysis in ml kit in flutter

Tags: flutter, face-recognition, firebase-mlkit

I am building a flutter app which needs the emotion analysis feature using face recognition . So I tried out ML Kit but it doesn't support emotion analysis.  Then I tried using Azure or aws but they are all APIs that need time to process an image, I want it in real time. So is there any solution for integrating such a feature with **flutter** .

Comment: Azure does have it: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/face/

Comment: Also, I don't see where it takes time

Comment: You can also try these: https://socialmediaweek.org/blog/2017/08/4-machine-learning-emotion-detection-apis-need-try/

Comment: Great can you please provide a sample of using azure face recognition with flutter

Comment: What I mean with " real time " is that there should be an internet connection provided to make a call for the api. I want it to happen offline that's what I meant with real time

Comment: Have you tried building your own model?